# Is there a way to remove search result from the find tab in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 9.0.2 (I do not know about the newer versions, but I am afraid it will be the same) when you search for something and get the results in the *Find* tab, you can mark certain results as irrelevat by selecting them and pressing the <kbd>del</kbd> key and this will strike them out.

When you search for something very common, which can have 5000+ occurences, even by striking some results out, the *Find* tab becomes very bloated.

Is there a way to completely remove a result from the *Find* tab, instead of just striking it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When using Find/Replace in Path functionality and you know that you will get a lot of results it's better to limit your search scope by either specific path, specific file extensions or some custom scope (using Scopes functionality).
2. If such "limiting" cannot not help (e.g. you really need to go trough each occurrence) then use <kbd>Alt + Delete</kbd> (the `Remove` action).

   **Please note** that this action is most likely available since **PhpStorm v10 only** (it was added only recently).

   You can check if you have it and what the shortcut is via content menu:

   [image]

Comment: Ooh, so darkomen's answer was correct after all, except my PhpStorm version is simply too old. Thanks for the answer, LazyOne.

Comment: One more question, I upgraded to the newer (10th) version, tried to remove the reference and damn, it does what I wanted but it is slow as heck. The exluding works instantly, as it did. I tried to remove 5000 occurences and it took good 5 minutes to do so. Have you had a similar problem? I'm working on a network mounted disc, which, I am sure, adds some time to it.

Comment: Cannot really comment on such performance issue -- I simply do not have it: 1) my results count is MUCH smaller 2) all local. However you may submit performance issue ticket to the [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) for devs to have a look at it and advise if it's expected in such conditions or not (you will need to provide some details though -- project structure and location (how big; where is it located etc); idea.log; thread dumps; possibly capture CPU snapshot).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this keymap shortcut : **`ALT + SUPPR`** (*this remove the result out of the find tab*)

instead of

keymap shortcut : **`SUPPR`** (*this JUST exclude the result of the find tab with underline this not remove*)

EDIT :
This is the exact response for your issue. Look at this screenshoot which say all :)

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a shortcut for removing a result from the find tab. Pressing `alt`+`backspace` gives me the `Following files affected by this action have been already changed` error message. I think the shortcut may be used for restoring files instead. Thanks for the response, anyway.